# Instantiate empty csv variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm using methods to pick records from different csv files and I want to know how to create an empty variable that would act like a csv file. For Example...

an empty array would be `$array = @()`

an empty hash table would be `$hashTable = @{}`

a non-empty csv object would be `$csvFileRecords = Import-Csv $someFileName`

an empty csv object would be `????`

What would the syntax be?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "csv object" - `Import/ConvertFrom-Csv` instantiates a number of `psobject`s with properties constructed using the data in the csv file. An "empty csv object" in your terminology would be indistinguishable from an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "CSV object" is actually just an array (of `psobject`s).

```
$csvFileRecords = @()
```

To add new records to that array, you just need to add `psobject`s with appropriate attributes corresponding to the desired columns. One way to create a `psobject` with desired properties is from a hash table.

```
$obj = new-object psobject -property @{fname="Fiddle";lname="Freak"}
$csvFileRecords += $obj
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add a record as follows to the array? `import-csv $csvFile | %{If ($recordFound) {$record = $_}}`. For the `$record`, would I just do `$csvFileRecords += $record`?

Comment: Yep, when you're iterating (using `%{ }` or `foreach-object{ }`) through the items in an array that you've imported using `import-csv`, then `$_` will refer to a single `psobject`, which you can easily add to another array using `+=`.  The following line would work: `$csvFileRecords = @(); import-csv $csvFile | %{If ($recordFound) {$csvFileRecords += $_}}` (assuming you replace `$recordFound` with a valid conditional).

Answer (score 1):

Well, CSV's can't created from $null, but you could do something like this:

```
PS C:\> New-Object -TypeName System.Object | ConvertTo-Csv
#TYPE System.Object
```

But your challenge is that this doesn't work back and forth.  For example:

```
PS U:\> ((New-Object -TypeName System.Int32 ) | ConvertTo-Csv).GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------   
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

means that the output of ConvertTo-CSV is not null, but this shows where you've lost the pipeline:

```
PS U:\> ((New-Object -TypeName System.Int32 ) | ConvertTo-Csv | ConvertFrom-csv).GetType()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ ((New-Object -TypeName System.Int32 ) | ConvertTo-Csv | ConvertFrom-c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The help says:

```
Inputs
    System.Management.Automation.PSObject
    You can pipe any object that has an Extended Type System (ETS) adapter to ConvertTo-CSV.
```

So I bet your issue is that $null or blank doesn't have an ETS Adapter.

Here's some more reading on this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2011/11/22/psobject-and-the-adapted-and-extended-type-systems-ats-and-ets/